# Convergence of EM for Mixture of Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

Is the Mixture of Gaussians model (an example of latent class analysis) gauranteed to converge on a viable solution even on Unimodal data using the Expectation Maximization algorithm to estimate the classes?

EM guarantees it will find a local optimum, but what does that necessarily mean with regard to the parameters?

E.g. If I have (singlevariate or multivariate) gaussian data, and I try to fit a mixture model of two Gaussians on it, what is theoretically supposed to happen?

Comment: There do exist algorithms for fitting Gaussian mixtures with convergence guarantees (given some assumptions on separation of the true mixture components, or similar), following a method of moments (sometimes called spectral learning) approach rather than EM. See e.g. [Vempala and Wang (2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcss.2003.11.008).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming no restrictions on the variables $\mu_k$ and $\sigma_k$ (the means and standard deviations of the separate components of the mixture model), the EM algorithm may not converge on a local maximum, as the likelihood function is unbounded in this case.

To illustrate, suppose we observe data points $x_1, ..., x_n$ and we fit a two component Gaussian mixture model. Then the log likelihood can be written as

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n \log\left( p_1 \times f(x_i | \mu_1, \sigma_1)  + p_2 \times f(x_i|\mu_2, \sigma_2)\right)$

where $f(x|\mu, \sigma)$ is the pdf of the normal distribution with mean = $\mu$ and standard deviation = $\sigma$. Consider now the case if we set $\mu_1 = \bar x$ (mean of observed data) and $\sigma_1 = \hat \sigma$ (standard deviation of observed data), with $p_1 = p_2 = 0.5$ (side note: these values are somewhat arbitrary, used only getting a lower bound). Then the contribution to the likelihood function for each point will be at least

$\log(0.5 \times f(x_i|\bar x, \hat \sigma) )$

i.e. the contribution for each observation can be bounded from below for all values of $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2$. Then consider if we set $\mu_2 = x_1$. As $\sigma_2 \rightarrow 0$, $f(x_1 | x_1, \sigma_2) \rightarrow \infty$. Of course, this implies

$\log(0.5 \times f(x_1| x_1, \sigma_2) + 0.5 \times f(x_1 | \bar x, \hat \sigma)) \rightarrow \infty$

as well. Since the contributions of all the other observations are bounded from below by $\log(0.5 \times f(x_i|\bar x, \hat \sigma) )$, this implies that the likelihood function is unbounded.

Since the likelihood function is unbounded, if the EM algorithm approaches this infinite "peak", it will not converge. However, this likelihood typically *does* have non-degenerate local maximum, assuming $n$ is sufficiently large relative to $k$ (number of components). So the EM algorithm may find these non-degenerate local maximum, which are undoubtably better estimators than the degenerate solution. In fact, if $n$ is large relative to $k$, it is very likely to find a non-degenerate local max rather than to approach the degenerate solution.

Comment: Just to clarify a little: the reason the likelihood approaches $\infty$ when $\epsilon$ approaches 0 is that the likelihood contribution of $x_1$ approaches $\infty$ as component 2 "closes in" on it. The likelihood contributions of the other observations are prevented from approaching $-\infty$ by component 1.

Comment: I was not able to follow this argument, because the nature of the likelihood function must depend on the data but you make no reference to them at all. I suspect you might also need to make clearer distinctions between the true parameters and potential estimates of them. The wildly varied and inconsistent notation (bars, hats, subscripts, no subscripts, greek letters, and latin letters) provides no apparent help in deciphering what you really mean. Do you think you could clarify this answer?

Comment: I am bit confused at what $x_1$, $\hat s$, and $\bar x$  are referring to as well. Are you suggesting that the second gaussian is collapsing on one point, approaching a delta function?

Comment: Sorry, just cleaned it up a little. Does that make more sense?

Comment: And yes, the issue is that one of the components can collapse around a single point.

Comment: While it is exact the maximum of the likelihood is equal to $+\infty$, I have never observed an EM algorithm converging to that degenerate solution.

Comment: The problem here is with your assumption that $p_1=p_2 = 0.5$. This would never happen with $\mu_2=x_1$, since when you do the Bayesian update, this would ultimately imply that $p_2$ is very small compared to $p_1$ (since you're implying that the second Gaussian is completely determined by one point). Thus, this scenario won't ever happen (at least the way you've described it).

Comment: @Dorain: actually, this issue has nothing to do with the value of $p_1$ or $p_2$, as long as they are both positive. I merely fix them equal to 0.5 for simplicity, as if the likelihood is unbounded for fixed values of $p_1, p_2$ then it is unbounded if they are allowed to vary as well.